# How to display subcategories on click categories page wordpress categories

Tags: wordpress

How to display sub categories  on category page if category has subcategories else show posts of that categories wordpress category page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); // now you have the ID of the category
```

Now check if something is returned and do whatever from there:

```
$args = array('child_of' => $id);
$subcats = get_terms( $args ); 
if(!empty($subcats)){
    foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
     echo get_term_link( $subcat->slug, $subcat->taxonomy ); // for example
    }
} else {
  // do the usual stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try get_categories() with args child_of function like below.

```
$args = array('child_of' => 'category_id');

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
}
```

Also, `$category->count  ===0` then category has no post. we can use it to check that category's post.